# AIR custom window according Os

Tags: air, flash-builder

I created a window skin for my AIR application.
Close, maximise and minimise button are on top right corner and look like Windows 7.

But , mac user are desapointed, so my question is : is it possible to apply a different window skin according user Os?

If yes, how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can detect the underlying Operating System using capabilities class and then you can put your styling logic for that particular OS.

Comment: Yes but is it possible to have the same skin? Thanks